# Material Displacement Issue, mesh gets warped!

Tags: shaders, error, displacement

Hi everybody today I encountered a problem that every single texture suddenly does not work with the cycles displacement. I am sure that I have enabled the 'displacement and bump', turned on cycles rendering just like I always do. Previous projects worked perfectly fine however today this problem happened. Moreover the textures being used as base color would cause the mesh to turn into either diagonal patterns or patterns like the cube in the picture (where brick textures should always repeat themselves on every side of the cube but now they don't)

[image: Slanted transformation with displacement midlevel 0 and scale 1.7]

[image: Cube with brick texture as basecolor but not every face has the repeating pattern]

Comment: Please show the vertices of your mesh in edit mode.  Do you use UV Coordinates?

Comment: Hello, looks like your object lacks geometry for displacement, you should add least add a subdivision modifier set to 'Simple'

Comment: For your second picture: if you want the bricks to appear on all sides of the cube, you should use the _UV_ output socket of the _Texture Coordinate_ provided that you have unwrapped your object, (although primitives like the cube have UVs by default when they are added to the scene).